# How to export special characters to PDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have problem exporting some special characters (Serbian latin letters) to PDF using jsPDF.

I have applied converted fonts and managed to make it work for simple text but I can not make it work when exporting content of div element with id="exportContent".

This is the code that works and exports simple text with special characters:

```
function demoFontTypes() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.setFont('ARIALUNI'); // set font
    doc.setFontSize(10);
    doc.text('žsćdšclsdpžcslcpsžclpsdpžclsdžpclsdžclpsć', 10, 10);
    doc.save('test.pdf');
}
```

I am trying to export content of div element with this code and I can not make it export these characters (žćđšč)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btnPDF").click(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "A4");
    var source = $("#exportContent")[0];
    var margins = {
        top: 30,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 50,
        width: 522
    };
    doc.setFont('ARIALUNI'); // set font
    doc.fromHTML(
        source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
        margins.left, // x coord
        margins.top, {
            // y coord
            width: margins.width // max width of content on PDF
        },
        function(dispose) {
            // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
            //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
            doc.save("Test.pdf");
        },
        margins
    );
    });
});
```

I need to be able to export content of div element with special characters (Serbian latin)

Comment: did you try this https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF#use-of-utf-8--ttf ?

Comment: Yes I tried this. The font that I use in code (ARIALUNI) is converted using this tool and because of this it works in the first example but I can not make it export div element with special characters